# Unexpected behavior of FTS Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Following select

```
select name, plainto_tsquery('russian', name) tbl_tokens, plainto_tsquery('russian', 'корневые продукты') const_tokens
from product_catalog.product p
WHERE 1=1
  and id = 1
```

returns next recordset

| name | tbl_tokens | const_tokens |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Корневой продукт | 'корнев' & 'продукт' | 'корнев' & 'продукт' |

tbl_tokens and const_tokens is equal

But query:

```
select name, plainto_tsquery('russian', name) tbl_tokens, plainto_tsquery('russian', 'корневые продукты') const_tokens
from product_catalog.product p
WHERE 1=1
    and id = 1
    and name @@ plainto_tsquery('russian', 'корневые продукты');
```

returns empty result and I don't understand the reason

Russian dictionary and config are present:

```
select d_t.dictname, d_t.dictinitoption, d_t.tmplname, n.nspname, n.nspacl 
from
      (select d.dictname, d.dictinitoption, d.dictnamespace, t.tmplname 
       from pg_ts_dict as d join pg_ts_template as t on (d.dicttemplate=t.oid)) as d_t 
            join pg_namespace as n on (d_t.dictnamespace=n.oid)
```

| dictname | dictinitoption | tmplname | nspname | nspacl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| russian_stem | language = 'russian', stopwords = 'russian' | snowball | pg_catalog | {postgres=UC/postgres,=U/postgres} |

gin index is present, but not used. EXPLAIN show Seq Scan (may by for very small table)

```
CREATE INDEX idx_fts_name
    ON product_catalog.product USING gin
    (to_tsvector('russian'::regconfig, name::text))
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem

instead of

```
'name @@ plainto_tsquery('russian', 'корневые продукты');'
```

i used

```
'to_tsvector('russian'::regconfig, name::text) @@ plainto_tsquery('russian', 'корневые продукты');'
```

it's working and gin index is used after growing the table "product"